# Assigning pixel values to a specific region

Tags: pixel, fill, region, imagej

Say that I select a region in `ImageJ`. How can I for instance for the pixels in that region, give them the value of `1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Run *Image > Color > Color Picker...* to choose the color value. The ImageJ status bar tells you the exact value while you move the mouse over the color.
- Run *Edit > Fill* to fill the current selection with the current foreground color value.

By running the [recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub%3aRecord...) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*) while performing these commands, you get the answer how to do this e.g. in Java:

```
ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
IJ.setForegroundColor(1, 1, 1); // this will result in value 1 in an 8-bit image
IJ.run(imp, "Fill", "slice");
```

Alternatively, you can use a lower level [API call](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/):

```
ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
ImageProcessor ip = imp.getProcessor();
Roi roi = imp.getRoi();

ip.setColor(1);
ip.fill(roi);
```